# Redraw JQplot bar chart with new data and tick labels

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jqplot

My code successfully draws a chart with data and tick labels retrieved as `JSON` object from `PHP`. Now at one point i want to refresh the chart but with slightly different data and different tick labels without creating a new chart.

```
$.jqplot.config.enablePlugins = true;
    var freqs1 = [];
    var freqlabels1 = [];

    var dataRendered1 = $.ajax({
        async: false,
        url: 'MY_URL',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) {
            if (data.length) {
                freqs1 = data[0];
                freqlabels1 = data[1];
            }
        }
    });

    var plot1 = $.jqplot('chartdiv', [freqs1], {
        animate: !$.jqplot.use_excanvas,
        seriesDefaults:{
            renderer:$.jqplot.BarRenderer,
            pointLabels: {
                show: true
            },
            rendererOptions: {
                barWidth: 12
            }
        },
        title:'Test',
        axes: {
            xaxis: {
                renderer: $.jqplot.CategoryAxisRenderer,
                ticks: freqlabels1,
                label: "Test 1",
                tickOptions:{textColor : 'rgb(39, 125, 175)', fontSize: '9pt'}
            },
            yaxis: {
                label: "Test 2",
                labelRenderer: $.jqplot.CanvasAxisLabelRenderer,
                tickOptions:{textColor : 'rgb(39, 125, 175)', fontSize: '9pt'}
            }
        },
        highlighter: { show: true }
    });
```

now when button is clicked lets say I have an ajax call that gets the new data and tick labels

```
 $(document).on('click', '#refresh_new', function() {
     $.ajax({
        async: false,
        url: 'MY_URL',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) {
                 var newData = data[0];
                 var newTicks = data[1];

                 //HOW DO I REFRESH CHART WITH NEW DATA AND TICKS FOR x-AXIS
        }
    });
 });
```